# Bit Bucket - How to clone only one branch in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I have one main repository "Production" and two branches "Development 1" and "Development 2".

To work on development branches, I had to clone the main branch first. I do not require this but I need to allow my team to checkout only the branch.

Right now, I would like to make my team to clone directly "Development 2" to work,commit and push only to it. Also, I need a workflow for my approval of Individual's commit instead of merging it directly to the branch.

How to achieve these ?

**Update :**

Unfortunately, the duplicate post has helped partially. I have created a [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970910/android-studio-how-to-clone-only-one-branch-in-android-studio) to explain why it is partially helped and to find the complete solution.

Comment: You do not clone a branch. You clone the repo. AFAIK you can do a shallow clone, but not clone only one branch (that doesn’t make much sense to me).

Comment: I was wrong, as proven by the answer in the target duplicate question.