# How to clone only one branch in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, bitbucket

I have posted the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962738/bit-bucket-how-to-clone-only-one-branch-in-android-studio) to find the complete solution but unfortunately/mistakenly it has marked as [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

The answer posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git) post has partially help me. But I still need to know how to clone single branch in Android studio. In Android studio, I could see an option to mention the URL (xxxxxxxx.git) and password but it actually clones main repository but there is no option to clone the branch repository directly and I still want to know how to setup the workflow for my approval when my team pushes the code.

**Update:**

I had to share my credentials(with admin rights) to my team for cloning . Is there any way to let them use their own bit bucket credentials for cloning in **Android Studio** ? Currently, Android studio requires to enter the repository URL and password for cloning but not user ID.

Please anyone guide me to find out the solution.

Comment: I was one of the people who marked your earlier question duplicate.  Maybe you can tell us why you think you need to clone a single branch?  Keep in mind, that for some branches, cloning the entire repo might be a necessity in order to bring in all relevant information.

Comment: I need my team to have only the branch for security purpose . I want to restrict them to make any changes in master repository. As  Android studio have the option to switch the branches easily , there is the possibility of some member in the team can mistakenly make the changes in main  repository of local and realize when committing/pushing it. Even if they do push, it should not impact on cloud branch directly instead there should be a workflow for my approval.

Comment: No...the client should not be the sentinel here.  You need to configure your Git repo to block/prevent unwanted pushes/clones on certain branches.  Most likely, you'll want to lock down the `master` branch heavily to make sure no debs accidentally push directly to it (i.e. to production).

Comment: I agree with your point. I will find out the way to lock it down. I have another query which I have updated in my question.

Comment: AFAIK the only two ways to authenticate to a Git repo (e.g. Bitbucket, GitHub, Stash, etc.) is by entering credentials (i.e. username/password), or by using SSL certificates.  Maybe look into SSL and see if that might help.